# SwiftRealm how to check if a Realm Object has a primary key or not?

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

Sometimes we may need to check if the realm object has primary key or not. Like if we want to do `func add<S>(_ objects: S, update: UpdatePolicy = .error) where S : Sequence, S.Element : Object`. If an object already exists in the Realm with the specified primary key and the update policy is `.modified` or `.all`. The `.error` is for objects without a primary key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using `object.objectSchema.primaryKeyProperty == nil` to check if the object has the primary key or not.